# Play vimeo video onmouseover and pause onmouseout

Tags: jquery, vimeo, froogaloop

I have a page which contains several vimeo videos, embedded in the standard iframe way.  I have a reference to froogaloop.js (http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js) in the HTML head and also jquery (v 1.4.2).  What I want to do is to be able to play each video onmouseover and pause onmouseout.

I've set up a JSFiddle page here: http://jsfiddle.net/g2Z2B/ which shows what I'm wanting to do - essentially just bind the video play/pause to the jquery onmouseover/onmouseout events - but no matter how much I read through the API documentation I just can't get anything to work.  I've tried pulling apart the API demo page here: http://player.vimeo.com/playground but can't even get that to work on mouseover - plus whenever I try to strip out the unwanted stuff it breaks too.  All I'm looking to do is something mega-simple.

If anyone could point me in the right direction here I'd be most grateful!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So the first thing is that you should be grabbing the player with Froogaloop's custom `$f` selector. If you look at `playground.html` this is done on line 223:

```
froogaloop = $f(player_id)
```

Additionally, you should be calling `.api('play')` rather than just `('play')`. Complete code might look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var player = $("#player_7256322");
        froogaloop = $f(player[0].id);

    player.mouseover(function(){
        froogaloop.api('play');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        froogaloop.api('pause');
    });
});
```

Fixed fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/g2Z2B/1/